# How do I not allow a user to remove the original form in an extend forms javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html

I am trying to implement this function taught in this site to allow users to extend forms, it works fine but the first/original form also has a remove button, so a user can actually remove the only form (although he/she can add it back). How do I not display the remove button for the first form?

the html:

```
<div id="readroot" style="display: none">

<input type="button" value="Remove review"
    onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />

<input name="cd" value="title" />

<select name="rankingsel">
    <option>Rating</option>
    <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
    <option value="good">Good</option>
    <option value="ok">OK</option>
    <option value="poor">Poor</option>
    <option value="bad">Bad</option>
</select><br /><br />

<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="review">Short review</textarea>
<br />Radio buttons included to test them in Explorer:<br />
<input type="radio" name="something" value="test1" />Test 1<br />
<input type="radio" name="something" value="test2" />Test 2

</div><form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/show_params.cgi">

<span id="writeroot"></span>

<input type="button" onclick="moreFields()" value="Give me more fields!" />
<input type="submit" value="Send form" /></form>
```

the javascript:

```
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    function moreFields() {
        counter++;
        var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
        newFields.id = '';
        newFields.style.display = 'block';
        var newField = newFields.childNodes;
        for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
            var theName = newField[i].name
            if (theName)
                newField[i].name = theName + counter;
            }
        var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
        insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
    }
    window.onload = moreFields;
</script>
```

Comment: i'm not sure why you would display a form you don't want to display. you could hide it, but then you're code wouldn't work.

Comment: The code above displays one form initially before any action. But the thing is it also display the remove button so a user can remove the only form (not additional forms as the user adds on). My aim to to make sure the first form cannot be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, if you do NOT want to show the form by default all you need to do is to remove the call to the moreFields() method on page load.

By removing the very last line of your js script

```
window.onload = moreFields;
```

you would prevent a form from being created on page load. Here's the adapted code in JFiddle with and without the window.onload call so you can see it in action:

With OnLoad:
https://jsfiddle.net/hyyjzjh1/

Without OnLoad:
https://jsfiddle.net/hyyjzjh1/1/

**UPDATE:**

I've re-read the question and realized that Alvin wants to prevent the first form from being removed. I've played around with the code and I believe this would do the trick:

HTML:

```
 <body>
      <div id="readroot" style="display: none">
             <!--Hide the button by default-->
            <input type="button" value="Remove review" onclick="RemoveReview(this)" style="display: none" /><br /><br />

            <input name="cd" value="title" />

             <select name="rankingsel">
                <option>Rating</option>
                <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
                <option value="good">Good</option>
                <option value="ok">OK</option>
                <option value="poor">Poor</option>
                <option value="bad">Bad</option>
             </select><br /><br />

            <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="review">Short review</textarea>
            <br />Radio buttons included to test them in Explorer:<br />
            <input type="radio" name="something" value="test1" />Test 1<br />
            <input type="radio" name="something" value="test2" />Test 2

     </div><form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/show_params.cgi">

     <span id="writeroot"></span>

     <input type="button" onclick="moreFields()" value="Give me more fields!" />
     <input type="submit" value="Send form" /></form>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
   var counter = 0;
   function moreFields() {
      counter++;
      var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);

      //This will only run the second time a form is created. It basically unhides the Remove Review button
      if (counter >1)
         newFields.childNodes[3].style.display = "block";

      //A separate ID is assigned to each form which is later used to identify the form to be removed 
      newFields.id = counter;
      newFields.style.display = 'block';
      var newField = newFields.childNodes;
      for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
          var theName = newField[i].name
          if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
      }

      var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
      insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
  }

  function RemoveReview (node){
    //The check below is probably not needed since the remove button will never show for the first form but just in case...
    if (node.parentNode.id > 1)
       node.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(node.parentNode)
}
```

Comment: what happens if they click the remove button?

Comment: @WhiteHat, I've modified the code so that the remove button wont show for the first form. I'm also passing an unique id to each form which is not really needed in this case but gives an idea of how they could be accessed individually.

Comment: Thanks so much again. But I tried to run it on jsfiddle and it doesn't open a new form as I press the button.

Comment: You're welcome Alvin! Jsfiddle wraps the js code so the function declarations need to be changed to "window.functionName(){}" for it to work. Alternativelly you can set the "no wrap - in <head> option" in jsfiddle to prevent that behaviour. Here's a working version of it: https://jsfiddle.net/okt3uk16/